# Debugging a react-library build using Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-library

I have a library build using reactJS and vite https://github.com/gsharath/sample-for-st-lib , which I am using in another react project https://github.com/gsharath/sample-for-st .
When I do npm install , it installs the minified version of the library, which seems good so far.

This is what I have in my sample-for-st-lib library:

```
export const Button = ()=>{
  return(
    <button>My Button</button>
  )
}
```

This is my vite.config for my library

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/index.js')
      },
      name: 'sample-for-st-lib',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react','react-dom'],
    },
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

I am referring this in my project using:

```
import { Button } from "sample-for-st-lib/components"

function App() {

  return (
   <>
    <Button />
    Test library
   </>
  )
}
```

Now while doing dev work and to debug issues, I am using npm link to create link between the library and project, so that

- I need not publish the package every time
- Assumed, I can open developer tools and find out the component from my-new-package
  and debug it in developer tools ( chrome ). Adding a screenshot of dev tools where I can find the component that I am looking for.

[image]

I looked at sourcemap option in vite.config which doesn't seem to be helping here.

I understand that since I am using this as a library, we need to rely on storybook to see how the components looks during dev mode or write something in library as a wrapper which helps me to debug it there, but I am looking to find out a way to debug the components from where my library is used. Did someone encounter this before and have something to guide me.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Sorry for the not-so-good-formatting

Comment: Any reason you don’t use workspaces?

Comment: Not entirely sure how workspaces works. will it be helping me with this scenario?

Comment: Workspaces will manage the symlinks for you, however you still need to rebuild dependencies for the dependent apps to pick up changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to help debug during development with your current workflow, there are two key things to change from the github repos you linked to:

- `npm uninstall sample-for-st-lib` within `sample-for-st` (so you can properly link them with `npm`)
- add [`sourcemap`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-sourcemap) to the vite build in `sample-for-st-lib`, ideally behind some env var

From fresh checkouts, starting with `sample-for-st-lib`:

1. `npm install`
2. Add `sourcemap` to your vite build (`'inline'`)
3. `npm run build`
4. `npm link`

Now a fresh checkout of `sample-for-st`:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm uninstall sample-for-st-lib`
3. `npm link sample-for-st-lib`
4. `npm run dev`

From here you can go back to `sample-for-st-lib` make changes to `Button` and then, here is the key, **remember to run `npm run build`**, so the changes can be picked up by the vite dev server running for `sample-for-st`.

Intentionally cause an error in `Button` by calling a function that doesn't exist, rebuild, and you should be able to see the source code for Button in your dev tools.

Comment: Let me check this and get back tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: Slightly a bit of a process to again rebuild the library to see the actual changes. Is there something that can help me simplify the process?

Comment: Don’t use `sample-for-st-lib` as an npm dependency but rather a local `import`. By the very nature of your chosen architecture you need a rebuild to pick up changes from your node_modules dependencies. Set up a watch process to rebuild on changes.

Comment: You might be able to try something with package.json [imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#imports), or modifying the `main` field of `sample-for-st-lib`, but I wouldn’t recommend it. Just rebuild as needed and stick to the first-class semantics of how node_modules packages work.

Comment: Regarding the chosen architecture, asking this out of curiosity, is there a simpler way to do this? And I am complicating something which can be done easily ?

Comment: I’ve already mentioned in my previous comments you could keep both code bases in the same package and then changes won’t require a rebuild. You can also create a watch task that triggers the rebuild automatically. Software development is about tradeoffs, so you’ll have to decide in what direction you want the project to proceed. Your setup is not over complicated and quite normal. I’ve used it many times. As I also mentioned previously you might want to consider workspaces and house both packages in the same monorepo.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will reconsider workspaces.

Comment: No problem. Workspaces is the natural progression from manual symlinks if your project has multiple packages where at least one has a dependency on another.

Comment: Yes. you are right. Workspaces are awesome. Thanks a lot for suggesting me this.